# Not creating swf file when testing movie

Tags: adobe, flash, actionscript-2

I have created a small flash project with 6 Scenes(two scenes contain flv clips 2 minutes each(1560 frames)). If I test each scene separately it runs perfectly, but when I try to run the whole movie it runs for 10 minutes "Exporting SWF Movie" and then stops without any errors or warning and without running project or creating swf file. I am using Adobe Flash Professional cs5.5. Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash has a limit on how many frames there may be, it's just about that number you have. To troubleshoot it you could either split the timeline into two separate symbols (clips) and then attach the second once the first stopped playing. You could also load FLV instead of compiling it, or compile it as a binary tag and then use [`NetStream.appendBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#!flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes%28%29) to play it.